# Как растянуть 5 элементов на всю ширину toolbar?

Tags: java, android

Есть 5 item в menu, как сделать так, чтобы эти 5 элементов располагались на всю ширину toolbar?

Comment: пардон, давал ответ для табов =_=

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Меню в тулбаре не предназначено для такого. Вам надо заменить тулбар и меню на самописный кусок разметки. Т.е. создаёте контейнер, в него кнопки, на кнопки вешайте слушатели нажатий.

Comment: Юрий, знаете, в приложениях делаю кнопки внизу экрана(навигация), как правильно их реализовать?

Comment: @АнтонМартынов, однозначного ответа дать нельзя. Вообще такое делают через BottomBar. Для этого на GitHub есть несколько либ и недавно появившееся гугловое решение. Но иногда их проще сделать через табы. TabLayout от гугла вам в помощь. Если дизайн совсем навороченный - проще самому сверстать и закодить чем готовые решения подгонять

Comment: А в чем проблема все это сделать, как вы выше написали,через свой кусок разметки?

Comment: @АнтонМартынов, всё зависит от ваших целей. Если вам нужно что-то совсем навороченное в плане дизайна - да, пилите сами. Если устроит стороннее решение - сэкономите много часов времени.

Comment: Смотреть в сторону BottomNavigationView, google в material, анонсировали месяца 4-5 назад это элемент мб больше и сделали отличный гайд. А когда-то был антипаттерном в devbytes...

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei и ЮрийСпб ,  у меня такая функциональность,при нажатии на кнопку в BottomNavigationView или в другом элементе(сторонние либы)  должна создать новая активность, а поверх нее фрагмент. В этом случае кнопки снизу скрываются, как в этом случае быть?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб что думаете?

Comment: @АнтонМартынов, ответил вам в вопросе

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645233/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-paralax-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82