# При открытии фрагмента с элементом paralax при скролле тормозит

Tags: java, android

Когда открывается фрагмент, при скролле вверх-вниз все очень тормозит.
В чем может быть причина?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_artist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/monro"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Имя"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <EditText
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:text="Алена"
           android:paddingLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/albums_artist_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Фамилия"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tracks_artist_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:text="АБДУЛЫХОВА-ОГЛЫ"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />




        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="EMAIL" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="ALENKKKA87@GMAIL.COM"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="НОМЕР ТЕЛЕФОНА"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="+7 (932) 233-45-42"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/monitored_switch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="32dip"
                android:text="Заморозить участие" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="ВЫ МОЖЕТЕ ПРИОСТАНОВИТЬ УЧАСТИЕ  В ПРОЕКТЕ. НОВАЯ ПРОГРАММА НЕ БУДЕТ ОТПРАВЛЕНА, ОТЧЕТ НЕ НУЖНО ЗАПОЛНЯТЬ."
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



        <include layout="@layout/notification_card_view_profile"></include>



    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Настройка уведомлений"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:src="@drawable/notification"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />





</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: по текущей информации можно сказать лишь то что причина в фрагменте с элементом `paralax`

Comment: @ermak0ff извиняюсь,код забыл добавить

Comment: @ermak0ff поправил

Comment: Возможно просто картинка в аппБаре тяжелая? Попробуйте её заменить на маленькую

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Когда в `NestedScrollView` находится другая скролящаяся вьюшка, то ей нужно запретить вложенный скроллинг методом `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)`. В вашем случае это `paralax`, которой видимо находится внутри инклуда.

Comment: в include находится CardVIew и он не Скроллится

Comment: А как параллакс может не скролиться?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? В include у меня находится CardView.
Где у меня в NestedScrollView находится скролящаяся вьшка?

Comment: Он скроллится , но подтармаживает, дело не в фото , так как фото весит 70кб и размером 100х100

Comment: Если внутри `NestedScrollview` нет скролющейся вьюшки то его вообще использовать не нужно. Подойдёт `RelativeLayout` или `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Я не много не понимаю, что вы имеею ввиду под скроллющейся вьюшкой?

Comment: У меня в разметке в NestedScrollVIew вложены элементы, мне нужно их проскролить. Как мне это реализовать?

Comment: Этим вложенным вьюшкам нужно запретить скроллинг?

Comment: Как paralax может находится внутри инклуда?

Comment: `NestedScrollview` обычно используется когда в одном контейнере используется вьшка которая скролиться например `RecyclerView` или `ScrollView` и обычные вьшки без поддержки скроллинга `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Добавьте лучше разметку инклуда.

Comment: Добавил, у меня внутри NestedScroll LinearLayout

Comment: Как я и говорил вам нет смысла использовать `NestedScrollview` . Поменяйте его на `ScrollView` и все должно работать нормально.

Comment: вы не правы, используя ScrollVIew,я не могу подннять изображение,проскролив вниз, наверх скролится будут тольок элкменты , а картинка скроется

Comment: Что скажете????

Comment: Вот точная суть проблемы
" меня нет плавной прокрутки этого списка. то есть скролл стопарится ровно на том моменте, когда оторвал палец от дисплея"

Comment: Да, я понял суть. Просто у меня была такая же проблема и я ее смог решить так как описал в ответе. Просто в вашем случае нужно найти у чего конкретно нужно отключить nested скролл.

Comment: Это однозначно как то связанно с Coordinator layout и его свойствами. Потому что без него бы все работало.